# Why do same ssd (in terms of brand and storage) report different capacity?

Tags: ssd, disk-space

I have two Samsung 850 evo 500 gb ssds. The old one which I bought a year ago reports 465.76 GB (476940 MB), and the recently bought one reports 465.75 GB (476924 MB) on the disk management. So the second one reports 16 MB less.

Here's [a link](http://www.guru3d.com/news-story/samsung-releases-850-evo-msata-and-m-2.html) that says formatted capacity is 465.76 GB.
So did I get a faulty ssd? What does missing 16 MB signify?

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, when you buy a Samsung SSD with a specific size, the device itself actually has more storage than this.

The reason is, that part of the storage is reserved to exeucte TRIM commands well. This makes it so that there is enough free space available to reorder data on the fly which keeps the SSD fast.

This means, that the data available is controlled using the controller. 16 MB is a base 2 number, so it is very likely the cause of a rounding error due to more internal storage so the TRIM performs better, or the filesize was lowered by 16MB because experimentation yielded this to preduce better results in the long run when it comes to keeping the SSD fast.